# ViewModel To Model Use ExpressMapper List<object> to List<Model> as Field

Tags: mvvm, mapping, automapper

My Model Is :

```
 public class Product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag>  Tags { get; set; }
}

 public class Tag
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

And View Model Is :

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

im using ExpressMapper To Mapping.
could it be map productviewModel List Tags To public ICollection  Tags?

Answer (score 0):

You can register your mappings like that:

```
 Mapper.RegisterCustom<Tag, string>((tag) => tag.Name);
            Mapper.Register<Product, ProductViewModel>();
            Mapper.Compile();
```

Here is working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2r7l4z